How can I embed a simple YouTube video, while being able to still scroll in the SingleChildScrollView as normal?
Using webview_flutter_platform_interface means the YouTube video can be embedded normally and works perfectly, except one can only scroll the SingleChildScrollView when the mouse is around/above/below the video. Implementing pointer_interceptor means there can now be a layer placed over the video that prevents its hogging of the scroll view. However, this means the whole video cannot be interacted with. How do I simply embed a YouTube video normally?

you can use iframe from this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html
